# Can I define a new connection / Entity manager within a Bundle configuration?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to define a Bundle that helps to index some data (from an Entity) within a sqlite fts table, in order to do some full-text search.

I know I can define alternate connection and Entity Manager using the `app` config file (like shown in the cookbook), but I was wondering if it was possible to do so within the bundle configuration - by defining, for example, a service with the `doctrine` service injected, so that it can instantiate a new connection.

Sqlite is not mandatory, it can be any database type (supported by doctrine).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you have a look at the WebProfilerBundle? It uses sqlite, so it does what you need.

Comment: I actually did, but too fast apparently. Let's dive again in the code ...

Comment: it is the `Profiler` service (within `HttpKernel`) which creates and manages Sqlite DB from scratch ...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) for how they handle multiple persistence layers (ORM, Couch, MongoDB). You would essentially be doing the same thing. It's just a matter of loading different configurations depending on the driver specified in app/config/config.yml.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it it not possible. Also database connections should be managed centralized in app/config.yml.

I would suggest to define the connection there and add a configuration option to you bundle where you can specify wich connection to use for the indexing stuff.

```
# app/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname:               database
                host:                 localhost
                user:                 user
                password:             secret
                driver:               pdo_mysql
            my_data_index:
                dbname:               database
                driver:               pdo_sqlite

# configuration option of you bundle
acme_indexer:
    connection: my_data_index
```

Then in your bundle you can read this config option and obtain the connection/entity manager and inject it into your indexing service.

**Edit:**

You can for sure create a custom connection programaticly in your bundle

```
$params =   array(
    'driver'    =>'pdo_sqlite',
    ....
);

$factory = $container->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory')
$connection = $factory->createConnection($params);
```

But as i said before it is bad practice because you would evade the symfony standart way of defining database connections.